# 2006 Nissan Altima Not Starting When Engine Is Hot

Tags: starting, nissan

If I drive it for a while, it will not start back up until it cools down.  The engine is not running hot, it turns over when trying to start, it just will not start until it cools down. I have been told it was the starter, the alternator or the fuel pump.  I can't afford to fix all these, especially if they're not the problem. Does anybody have any ideas about what could be going on?

Comment: They have also mentioned maybe a broken wire expanding when hot and going back togehter when it cools down.

Comment: When you say "crank", you mean "start", right? If I make that replacement, your question makes sense.

Comment: Camshaft position sensor. My money is on a sensor being bad when hot.

Comment: @cory Wouldn't that throw a code?

Comment: @THarvell Is the check engine light on?

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Which engine do you have? Nissan engines tend to have certain patterns of failure.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's a few things here. First, what it's not:

- **starter:** if the engine is turning over, the starter is working fine.
- **alternator:** the alternator charges the battery and has absolutely nothing to do with starting the engine. If your battery is fully charged and the alternator belt isn't seized, the alternator has nothing to do with a no-start.

Now, what it could be and how you can tell. An engine needs 3 things to start:

- **fuel:** delivered by the fuel pump. First things first, with the car off, turn the key to "on" without starting. If you hear a hum coming from the back of the car, the fuel pump is working. Second thing, fuel pressure. Get a fuel pressure tester, hook it up to your fuel line near the engine and measure the fuel pressure while the fuel pump is humming. Third, fuel injectors. Check your fuel injectors for electrical continuity, that will tell you if they are working or not.
- **compression:** Get a compression tester ($15-$20) and do a compression test.
- **spark:** If your engine has ignition wires, get a timing light and test every single one while someone is trying to start the car. You should see very regular flashing.

All that being said, a warm engine not starting, it could be your fuel injectors are leaking and flooding the engine. That "broken" wire theory is also plausible. Ignition wires are usually affordable, and you can probably do this yourself. Twist and pull to remove, twist and push to plug in. Only ever disconnect 1 ignition wire at a time, so your replacement is connected to the correct spot at both ends.

Answer (score 1):

No experience with Nissan, but Honda cars of that time and older often had a main relay/fuel relay board that would fail when the car interior was warm.  (solder crack).

It would fit with your symptoms, and it's a lot cheaper and easier to replace that than a fuel pump.